# Android Studios: How do I make a code that allows my app to do a certain action after a written number of clicks?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, onclicklistener

I understand the OnClickListener to some extent, and  I understand that you can add what action you want the button to do after one click, but how do I make the button initiate an action after 5 clicks for example.

Comment: Keep a counter, `counter++; if (counter > 5) { /* do the thing */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an instance field which tracks the number of times pressed, then in your onClickListener just use that same if statement
So your instance field could look like this:

```
private int counter = 0;
```

Then in your onclick listener:

```
counter++;
if(counter > 5) {
    //do the thing, call a method, whatever
 }
```

If you are looking for permanent storage, to keep track of the number of times it has been pressed that will persist after a user closes the app, use SharedPreferences, but I don't think that's what you are looking for here so I won't include the code.

If you aren't familiar with an instance field, its just a fancy word for a global variable(Yes Java purists I know that's not technically accurate). Just declare it right below your class declaration, and not inside any method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//instance fields go here
private int counter = 0;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```